# WCF Service won't execute incoming message

Tags: wcf

Why would WCF be able to receive a message just fine, yet freezes when it tries to execute the Operation on the server?

Specifically according to the Service Trace Viewer, it successfully opens the ServiceChannel and but is unable to open an InstanceContext or do any other action. No exceptions are thrown, it simply stops. What's really got me confused is that I setup my code just like I normally do, but, this service doesn't want to run, I have two other servers full of services that work great.

I'm thinking its a minute detail in the configuration somewhere that I missed, but I can't find it. Anybody have any suggestions of where I should start looking?

[image]

Comment: Please supply more detail about the service and its bindings and behaviors. In particular, what is the instancing mode, transaction mode, session, etc.

Comment: You might also want to post an excerpt of the trace viewer output. In particular, I'm wondering if you ever got to the "Receiving a message on a channel".

Comment: Well, it won't let me post a picture so i'll have to use a link.

http://www.prospectivesoftware.com/temp/WCFError1.png

That's the Svctrace excerpt. I am getting the message received over a channel notification.

Instance Mode is PerCall.
It's a sessionless WSHTTP binding (although a sessionful NetTCPBinding yields an identical results)
Transactions/Reliable Sessions are off on WSHTTP, and on in TCP.
It's hosted as a LocalSystem service.
ProtectionLevel is None.
Namespace is NOT http://tempuri.org
ConcurrencyMode is Multiple.
No sync context.

Comment: If you have InstanceMode=PerCall, there's absolutely no point in having ConcurrencyMode=Multiple - each request will get a new instance of your service class to handle the request. Set that ConcurrencyMode to Single - no point in making things unnecessarily complicated....

Comment: Good point, I'll do that, but since we have another service that runs fine in that configuration I doubt that's it, in fact I copied over the ServiceBehavior from the one that works, which is how it got the Multiple in the first place...

Comment: Tried that, no change, have also tried using a different account for the service, no joy.

Comment: @Beller: what's those red entries in the service trace?

Comment: Those are the exceptions that get thrown when the request times out and the connection is abnormally terminated, the timestamps on those are ~2mins after the message is recevied. I've also confirmed that this effects all my services in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, although I have to fault WCF for not behaving in an expected manner. The ManualFlowControlLimit was set to zero on all service hosts. I propose that WCF should have popped an exception or other notification of the limit reaching zero, at least in the trace logs if not the code itself. To that effect, i've also decided to open a case on Microsoft's Connect site to see what they think.

The reason it was set to zero is that we use a tool that we built to generate our WCF Services/Hosts/Bindings and it defaulted to zero, we are updating our tool to use the default value when it is set to zero.

Thank you all for your patient assistance!